# Tree structure in SQL with multiple parents

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a list of users.

Each user has a rank from 1-8, a unique id and a parent id.

I need to create a SQL query that outputs a list of users with their parents in their respective columns.

I imagine I would start at level 8 (the lowest) and add all the values there. Then look for each of their parents and add those values in the level 7 column, then look for each of their parents and add those values in the level 6 column, and so it goes.

I have tried many variation of this and can't seem to figure it out.|

Previous answers don't seem to answer this use case.

Comment: provide some sample data and expected output so we can help you. should be relatively simple with use of recursive cte along with pivot ...